# Why does Firefox v42.0 on Mac disable jQuery in normal windows?

Tags: jquery, firefox

There is the setting under Privacy / «Tracking Protection in private windows». It is ENABLED per DEFAULT. Our [web site](http://www.zwischengas.com/de/index.html) gets executed but without any jQuery code in Firefox v42, hence any buttons do not work anymore!
If you disable that option (tracking protection OFF), everything works fine.

Tested on Mac OSX 10.10.5

Is this a bug or any idea why Firefox thinks that our jQuery code is malicious?

Comment: It seems unlikely that jQuery specifically would be blocked. Could it be that the CDN you are using for jQuery is associated with harmful tracking?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? our jQuery code does not load external resources. From a namespace point of view, the Google tracking code runs in the same jQuery namespace as our own code... Maybe Firefox just disables the whole namespace if it detects tracking code in there...?